# managing C++ large static library

Tags: c++, linux, unix, static-libraries

I'm collaborating on a C++ project with around 100,000 lines of code, which is heavily intertwined and builds into two libraries the "util" library and the "physics" library. The resulting lib files are extremely large, being 265Mb/1.2Gb in size when compiled with debugging symbols, but even without they are 161Mb/700Mb. These are then used in some 30 different executables.

The problems is that debugging becomes very hard: you change one line and then making a single executable takes 30 seconds on a powerful machine with SSD.

The most obvious strategy of managing this is to split the lib file into many. How many, i.e. what is an ideal size for a lib file? Is there anything wrong with splitting just alphabetically? (i.e. all .o files starting with a or A go to libphysicsA.a, etc.)?

Comment: A sensible strategy would be splitting the library into logical groups of functionality (_e.g_ matrix manipulations, transformations, minimization algorithms, _etc._). Using alphabetical ordering as a splitting criterion would be confusing (and there is no actual guarantee that the first letters of all functions have uniform distribution :] ). Anyway, the splitting may or may not result in a slightly faster linkage, but the compilation would probably take the same time (assuming your build environment supports basic incremental builds).

Comment: I agree with Eitan on how to split files. Make it easy to understand, and probably it will also be faster to link.

By the way, is the time for the executable spent mostly on compilation or linking? If it's compilation, could it be due to a massive usage of templates? That sometimes forces the double compilation of large template classes. As it happens in a project I'm involved... -.-

Comment: bartgol, yes, massive use of templates, so compiling is slow, but then even just "ar" command takes some times since it needs to dump a Gb onto a disk. I was hoping for some magic solution... :)

Comment: This question appears to be too design/discussion-oriented for Stack Overflow, which is for specific questions about coding that can have definite answers. Discussions of high-level design concepts and best practices are more appropriate for [programmers.se]. Please read [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/82990/228805) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a long time compilation, so obviously you have to continue splitting until compile time become satisfactory. It's better to split library by meaning of it's parts or by use frequency. Put together those modules that related mostly by meaning, or used frequently/infrequently. Splitting just alphabetically will lead your project to use too much different library parts and even all of them, slowing compilation to initial time value.